# Rails 4 has_many :through w/ check_box_tag - only one side of associate being saved to join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to Rails and I've been trying to extend Michael Hartl's tutorial in various ways. One of which is to model user interests using a has_many :through association. I have the following models set up:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_interests, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :user_interests
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_interests, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :interests, through: :user_interests
end

class UserInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user    
    belongs_to :interest
end
```

My user_interests controller:

```
def index
end

def create
    @user_interest = current_user.user_interests.build(params[:interest_ids])
    if @user_interest.save
        redirect_to current_user
        flash[:success] = "Interests updated!"
    else
        render 'index'
    end
end

def destroy
    @user_interest = UserInterest.find(params[:user_id][:interest_ids])
    current_user.user_interests(@user_interest).destroy
end
```

The view:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.user_interests.build(params[:interest_ids])) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[interest_ids][]", nil %>
    <% Interest.all.each do |interest| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[interest_ids][]", interest.id, current_user.interest_ids.include?(interest.id), id: dom_id(interest) %>
        <%= label_tag dom_id(interest), interest.activity %><br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Update interests", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

When I run the app I can select a check box and click the submit button but only the user id  is saved in the user_interests table. So it will look like:

```
id integer    user_id    interest_id    created_at_timestamp    updated_at_timestamp
    1           2155                      2014-04-06 ect...       2014-04-06 ect...
```

At first I was trying to use the users controller to create the association, but that was causing issues because I didn't have the interests check boxes displayed on the users#edit action, I wanted them to have their own page. What do I need to do to get the interest ids to save to the user_interests table along with the user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try with the following code.

```
def create
   interests = Interest.where(id: params[:user][:interest_ids])
   current_user.interests.push(interests)
   flash[:success] = "Interests updated!"
   redirect_to current_user
end
```